# Magento Installation Roadmap Clarification

Tags: php, mysql, magento, phpmyadmin, migration

I am working to upgrade a Magento 1.5 site to 1.8.1 -- I have followed the roadmap found at the link below:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-upgrade-roadmap

This article says that I should 
(1) install Magento fresh on a Dev Server, which I've done. Doing this requires an empty database to install Magento 1.8 with, which I've done.

(3) Import Production Database onto an empty Development Database instance.

The only way I've found to import a database as large as this one (~3GB) is to use BigDump to take my SQL dump from PHPMyAdmin and import it into a blank database. I am not confident in this plan though.

Is there a way that Magento offers to help move databases between Production and Development servers? The Roadmap left that a bit vague.

Comment: Is the only thing leaving you in vague is to import a DB with size 3 GB ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use phpMyAdmin's uploadDir feature, where you upload the file via FTP or SFTP, then point phpMyAdmin to the directory. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the installation folder for phpMyAdmin so I couldn't find a way to change that setting. However, I managed to use BigDump successfully with a Magento-made Backup Dump.